# Nodejs/Express: Facing issues while working on routings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

viewController.js

```
const Book = require('./../models/bookModel')
const APIFeatures = require('./../utils/apiFeatures.js')

exports.getOverview=async(req,res,next)=>{

  const features = new APIFeatures(Book.find(),req.query).filter().paginations()
  let getItAllProd = await features.getBook;
  res.render('overview',{
    data:getItAllProd,
    title:"trending books"
  })
  next()
}

exports.getOneBook =async(req,res,next)=>{
  const getThatBook = await Book.findOne({slug:req.params.id})
  res.render('onebook',{
    data:getThatBook
  })
  next()
}

exports.categories= async(req,res,next)=>{
  const getCate = await Book.find({category:req.params.category});
  res.render('overview',{
    data:getCate,
    name:req.params
  })
  next()
}

exports.paginationOfBook = async(req,res,next)=>{
  let pages = req.params.page
  pages = pages * 6 || 6;
  const limit = 6;
  let skip = pages-6;

  const getlimitedbook = await Book.find({}).limit(limit).skip(skip);
  res.render('overview',{
    data:getlimitedbook,
  })
  next()
}
```

viewRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const viewController = require('./../controllers/viewController')
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/overview',viewController.getOverview)

router.get('/overview/:category',viewController.categories)
router.get('/overview/:page',viewController.paginationOfBook)
router.get('/overview/:id',viewController.getOneBook)


module.exports = router;
```

using http://localhost:3000/overview I can get all the books and http://localhost:3000/overview/:category - using this I get the books by categories. but if I try to load the the for http://localhost:3000/overview/:page and http://localhost:3000/overview?:id - the data will not load up.. so below I did some changes in routing..

```
router.get('/overview',viewController.getOverview)
router.get('/overview/:id',viewController.getOneBook)
router.get('/overview/:category',viewController.categories)
router.get('/overview/:page',viewController.paginationOfBook)
```

Now I have access to the '/overview' and '/overview/:Id'. but not for others. the data is not loading for them. do you have any solution? so I can access all the routes.uuu

Answer (score 0):

First of all please elaborate you're question more. But I think the problem is in the following line:

```
 const getThatBook = await Book.findOne({slug:req.params.id})
```

edit this line to:

```
 const getThatBook = await Book.findById(req.params.id)
```

and call this route like this http://localhost:3000/overview/34234232...
Or change your "id" to "slug" in the following line.

```
 const getThatBook = await Book.findOne({slug:req.params.slug})
```

and call this route like this http://localhost:3000/overview/xyz_book_slug...

```
router.get('/overview/:slug',viewController.getOneBook)
```

and pass the book's slug property value when calling this route.